# APCu Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals

Tags: php, apcu

I tried to install APCu by pecl. The installation was smooth. However, PHP can't load APCu.

This is the error message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apcu.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apcu.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_signal_globals\n  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apcu.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apcu.so in Unknown on line 0

php-config:

> Usage: /usr/local/bin/php-config [OPTION]
>   Options:
>    --prefix            [/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30]
>    --includes          [-I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php/ext/date/lib]
>    --ldflags           [ -L/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libpng/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/unixodbc/lib]
>    --libs              [  -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lexslt -lresolv -ledit -lncurses -lldap -llber -liconv -liconv -lintl -lpng -lz -ljpeg -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl -lbz2 -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lm  -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lfreetype -lodbc -lodbc -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lz -liconv -lm -lxml2 -lxslt ]
>    --extension-dir     [/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212]
>    --include-dir       [/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/include/php]
>    --man-dir           [/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/share/man]
>    --php-binary        [/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/bin/php]
>    --php-sapis         [ apache2handler cli fpm cgi]
>    --configure-options [--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30 --localstatedir=/usr/local/var --sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-path=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/share/man --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar --enable-dba --enable-exif --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-mbregex --enable-mbstring --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --enable-sysvmsg --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-wddx --enable-zip --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local/opt/freetype --with-gd --with-gettext=/usr/local/opt/gettext --with-iconv-dir=/usr --with-icu-dir=/usr/local/opt/icu4c --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/opt/jpeg --with-kerberos=/usr --with-libedit --with-mhash --with-ndbm=/usr --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local/opt/unixodbc --with-png-dir=/usr/local/opt/libpng --with-unixODBC=/usr/local/opt/unixodbc --with-xmlrpc --with-zlib=/usr --with-readline=/usr/local/opt/readline --without-gmp --without-snmp --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/opt/libxml2 --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --libexecdir=/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/libexec --with-bz2=/usr --disable-debug --with-openssl=/usr/local/opt/openssl --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=_www --with-fpm-group=_www --with-curl --with-xsl=/usr --with-ldap --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-mysql-sock=/tmp/mysql.sock --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --disable-opcache --enable-pcntl --without-pear --enable-dtrace --enable-zend-signals]
>    --version           [5.5.30]
>    --vernum            [50530]

OS: OS X 10.11.3

Comment: I think you have more than one version of PHP, you must pass ```--with-php-config``` the correct ```php-config``` script when executing ```configure``` for apcu.